# Is there a way to chain multiple tailwind css classes on a single hover instance?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I was wondering if there is a way to chain multiple tailwind css classes on a single hover instance on an html element instead of using multiple hover instances.

For instance instead of this

```
<button class="hover:bg-blue-900 hover:text-white"></button>
```

whether you can have this or something else

```
<button class="hover:bg-blue-900:text-white"></button>
```

Comment: There isn't any proper way to do it.

Comment: I'm good with CSS and I decided to start learning Tailwind, I'm asking the same question and found no solutions... and this is just a turn-off for me! it transcends the purpose of this framework of writing less CSS. I think I'm gonna stick to vanilla CSS or learn SASS

Comment: If you're familiar with Styled Components or Emotion, check out Twin.Macro. It's able to group classes on variants with some extended syntax they've added to improve Tailwind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there isn't. As from the docs(https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states), you can see they themselves add multiple classes for focus/hover.

However you can create reusable styles to counter [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, we can't do variant grouping in tailwind CSS.
So to answer your question, As of now, there is no way to chain multiple tailwind classes on a single hover or any other pseudo-classes instance. The reason behind it is, it creates performance issues at the end.

According to Adam Wathan, the creator of TailwindCSS:

> ***Although the grouped syntax *looks* like less code when you're authoring it, it actually creates both a bigger CSS file *and* a bigger HTML file in production, making it a very black-and-white performance anti-pattern.
> It's nicer to write though, and the performance cost isn't a huge one, so still a chance we develop it further just for the developer experience for the people who like it. But admittedly hesitant to encourage anything that's bad for performance.***

Alternatively, We can use different strategies for reusing styles in our project which is described in the [tailwind documentaion](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles) which is also mentioned earlier by @amunim.

****Please read the whole tweet and form for more details:****
https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1461519820411789314
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8337

Comment: Thanks for the quote! Good to know a reason for this seemingly crazy choice. I hope they can make this work in the future though... tailwinds biggest weakness, ugly html and unreadable complex styles, would be much more improved by grouping pseudos.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same issue and was going to write a Tailwind plugin for that, but it turns out that it's hard to mess with the rules they have set. You can only extend it by adding new variants and utilities, but cannot do something like `hover:(text-white bg-red-500)`.

However, I did find out about [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro) that has this variant groups feature, so check that out.

Comment: +1 to Twin.Macro. We use it on a fairly large React project with Styled Components and haven't looked back. Being able to mix CSS-in-JS features with Tailwind is the best of both worlds, highly recommend!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it seems not. Maybe something that should be suggested to the team

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar, i wanted the text to change color when hover the **div**.
searching in the docs i found the 'group' that helped me:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state

i tried different types of hover like:
hover:bg-green-600 text-gray-50
hover:[bg-green-600 text-gray-50]
hover:(bg-green-600 | text-gray-50)

Maybe you can try wrapping the button in a div and add the **group** class

my code before, did not work like this

```html
<Link to='/home'>
  <div className="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer hover:(bg-green-600 text-gray-50)">
    <span className="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-500 font-bold">Home</span>
  </div>
</Link>
```

after using gruop

```html
<Link to='/home' className='group'>
  <div className="p-2.5 mt-3 flex items-center rounded-md px-4 duration-300 cursor-pointer group-hover:bg-green-600" >
    <span className="text-[15px] ml-4 text-gray-500 group-hover:text-gray-50 font-bold">Home</span>
  </div>
</Link>
```

with **group** when i hover the **div** it also change the **span** text color, like this the cursor don't need to be right on top of the word to make hover work.

but I still wish there was a way to put more than one class on the same hover, I hope they add it in the future...

hope it may help

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this functionality through tailwind. According to this docs (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gradient-color-stops) we need to broke our css statements for hover state in multiple separate hover class in a sequential order. Then it will be good to go. I have solved it in this way:

`<button class="hover:scale-105 hover:bg-blue-500">click me</button>`